# Cannot open wp-admin (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

**Fatal error: Cannot redeclare get_cli_args() (previously declared in    /home/u270125469/public_html/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-importer.php:271) in    /home/u270125469/public_html/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-importer.php on line 319**

On opening "abc.com/wp-admin" I'm getting the above error. How to resolve this error? This happened after I installed a plugin for importing the customizer file.

Comment: Rename the plugin folder in `wp-content/plugins`. This will deactivate the plugin and you can reach the wp-admin

Comment: [Disable a WordPress Plugin Without Access to Your Admin Area](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/wordpress/disable-a-wordpress-plugin/)

Comment: Disable any custom importer plugin you have installed

Answer (score 0):

```
function replace_text($text) {
    $text = str_replace('look-for-this-string', 'replace-with-this-string', $text);
    $text = str_replace('look-for-that-string', 'replace-with-that-string', $text);
    return $text;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'replace_text');
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach? While you're at it, please apply some indentation to aid in the readability.